# How to query for local JSON file in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

I'm trying to make a dynamic search but I am using a local JSON file. I have found plenty of information on how to query through an API, but I can't seem to figure out how to enter the JSON file for the query portion of my code. Below is the part that I am having issues with. Is there a way to add the file like I am trying to here (this is where the api url would go) or do I have to do something completely different? Thanks.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchItems = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    const result = await axios(
      `../../../static/movie-reviews.json?name=${query}`
    )
```

Comment: You cannot query directly, either try vanilla implementation or you can use lodash or underscore.js

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query like this.

you can instead filter the json like this

```
const data = require('../../../static/movie-reviews.json')

const filteredData = data.filter(dat => dat.name === query)
```